# Error while using Redis Expire command options

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, redis-cli

I am trying to set expiry on a key if expiry is not already set by using NX option of Expire command.

But I keep getting error from redis-cli, and when I try from code NX option gets ignored.

When I try to use Expire command from redis-cli I get following error

`127.0.0.1:6379> expire ns1 500 NX`

`(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'expire' command`

Redis version - v=6.2.6

Also If I try to do it programatically, expire command is ignored. Code below -

```
let res = await client.INCRBY('ns1', 5)
console.log('incr val ' + res)
res = await client.EXPIRE('ns1', 60, { 'NX': true }) // this should set expiry
res = await client.EXPIRE('ns1', 180, { 'NX': true }) //this should ignore setting expiry
res = await client.TTL('ns1')console.log('ttl expiry ' + res)`
```

The response I get for above is

`incr val 5`

`ttl expiry 180`

Any help to resolve this will be great

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.redis.io/commands/expire
"Starting with Redis version 7.0.0: Added options: `NX`, `XX`, `GT` and `LT`"